# Add a little 'x' so users can close the new user contributor indicator

Tags: feature-request, new-contributor-indicator

Please add a little 'x' in the corner of the new-contributor-indicator notification, such that users can click on the `x` to close this box.

Perhaps I appreciate the reminder but once I've read the reminder I don't need it anymore.

Comment: Better if they add option to disable this indicators at all in settings.

Comment: @Suvitruf One does not rule out the other.  I think those would be two distinct feature requests.

Comment: I like to see that warning, even in the answer windows. the persistant way to display it make sure I keep a good tone in my talk with the user