# Add option to hide contributor indicator completely

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, user-interface, new-contributor-indicator

I found this question: [Add a little 'x' so users can close the new user contributor indicator](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/314511).
But it's about a specific user question.

This indicator only distracts attention from the question itself. So, would be great if we could hide/disable this indicator completely. For example, you can add such option on the profile settings page.

As a workaround just for now, script for Tampermonkey:

```javascript
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Contributor indicator cutter
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      0.1
// @author       Suvitruf
// @match        *://*/questions/*
// @match        *://*/review/*
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==


(function() {
    'use strict';

    var doc             = document;
    var newNode         = doc.createElement ('style');
    newNode.textContent = '.new-contributor-indicator {display: none;}';

    var targ            = doc.getElementsByTagName ('head')[0] || doc.body || doc.documentElement;
    targ.appendChild (newNode);
})();
```

Comment: [Why people like workarounds so much? ...](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/372880/5267751)

Comment: @user202729 'cause we don't have choice)

Comment: Somewhat related: [Add a way for users to “opt out” of the new contributor indicator on their own posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/314474/add-a-way-for-users-to-opt-out-of-the-new-contributor-indicator-on-their-own-p)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

We won't consider adding an option that disables this completely. It would kind of defeat the purpose of even *having* the indicator at all if users can just go turn it off globally and never see it again, particularly for those users who definitely *should* be seeing it. If the indicator becomes too problematic to the point where we'd even consider this feature, we might as well just ditch the feature entirely.

By all means, users who really dislike it that much can modify the page to remove it, like any other element on the page one might find annoying. But we're not going to complicate the user settings page to make it easier for them to do so.

Comment: "for those users who definitely *should* be seeing", so you want to *impose* what people *should* see, right?

Comment: @Suvitruf We can't pretend like there aren't abusive users on the site that need to be reminded to be nice constantly. And we definitely don't want those users to be able to easily ignore those reminders.

Comment: If someone is not polite, he will be judged. Simple. This indicator will not make those people better. Probably, it would make things even worse. But this indicator distract polite people from the questions.

Comment: @Suvitruf And there are plenty of better solutions to that problem than implementing a profile setting that lets users just completely ignore everything. Like I said, removing the feature would be more likely than adding a profile setting.

Comment: I agree with you about complexity. But the *settings* was just an example of a solution. If you decide to do something with indicator you can choose better implementation, for sure (:

Comment: I was originally a big fan of letting folks turn off the indicator, but . . . yeah. You make a good point. This is one of those things that needs to be visible and obvious for it to work at all. On the other hand, now that someone's cobbled together a way around it . . . people can still ignore the warning. But hey, no reason to make it easier for those users to stick their fingers in their ears.

Comment: @HDE226868 no need to bother law-abiding users.

Comment: They could write logic that shows this indicator to, hm, users that *supposedly* are not polite.

Comment: @Suvitruf You might consider a different feature request that selectively shows it to certain users and hides it from users who have a track record of being polite, rather than just letting anyone hide it.

Answer (score 26):

As a workaround for until this is implemented (if ever), you can add the rule

```
##.new-contributor-indicator
```

to your favorite ad blocker to hide both the indicator beneath the usercard and in the answer field.

Comment: I added `##.js-new-contributor-label` and 
`##.ps-relative.js-new-contributor-indicator` to uBlock origin.